# Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue in ktor cors header

Tags: javascript, kotlin, ktor

I am building a simple REST API using ktor and used cors but when i send a simple get request with no headers data the server works fine but if i want the client to have say key:1 the server doesn`t respond me correctly, it says the problem is

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/test: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

so here is my ktor code

```kotlin
install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {
        }
    }
    install(ForwardedHeaderSupport)
    install(DefaultHeaders)
    install(CORS)
    {
        method(HttpMethod.Options)
        method(HttpMethod.Get)
        method(HttpMethod.Post)
        method(HttpMethod.Put)
        method(HttpMethod.Delete)
        method(HttpMethod.Patch)
        header(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowHeaders)
        header(HttpHeaders.ContentType)
        header(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin)
        allowCredentials = true
        anyHost()
        maxAge = Duration.ofDays(1)
    }
...
 get("test"){
            val a =  call.request.headers["key"]
            println(a)
            call.respond(Product(name = a))
        }
```

and my javascript code looks like this....

```js
fetch('http://shop-ix.uz:8080/test', {
 headers: {
 "key": "1" 
})
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => {    
     console.log(json);
   })
```

please help me

Comment: if you're getting a 403 as mentioned then it implies your OPTIONS request was rejected as not having adequate permissions. This might well be why the header is then missing. Try to investigate the permissions error first. By the way, your stated error message doesn't match your code - the URLs are different

Comment: I tested on localhost but the error is the same

Comment: ok well that explains that, but it doesn't explain the 403. You need to dig a bit deeper into your setup to see why a call to that URL returns Forbidden. Does it also return 403 Forbidden if you try to access the same result directly in your browser window (i.e. by pasting it into the address bar, not by using fetch())? I realise this will not generate an OPTIONS request, but it might at least show us if it's accessible via a regular GET. Then we can narrow down if the issue is specific to OPTIONS requests only, or a problem with the whole URL.

Comment: the regular get request works with the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to whitelist your headers like this:

```
install(CORS) {
  header("key")
}
```

This needs to be done with every custom HTTP header you intend to use.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all the headers and required methods should be allowed during Ktor CORS installation. I was facing the same issue, then I realized that I didn't add `allowHeader(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin)`
Although in the request header it was present. Because of that I am getting forbidden error (403)!

**My Request Header!**

```
Axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/connect',
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        params: {
          ...
        }
})
```

**Allowing CORS**

```
    install(CORS) {
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Options)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Post)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Get)
        allowHeader(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin)
        allowHeader(HttpHeaders.ContentType)
        anyHost()
    }
```

**Check that what your request header wants is allowed on the server during CORS.**

Comment: just bare in mind this is solution for Ktor version 2.x.x

Answer (score 1):

```
install(CORS) {
   exposeHeader("key")
}
```

difference between `header` and `exposeHeader` - first allow to make call with this header, but second allow to use it on client side